# problem building VTK-9.2.0.rc1 with cmake version 3.23.2

Tags: linux, eclipse, cmake, vtk

Hello i'm totally new to VTK and cmake, i'm trying to build VTK with make command (on linux) but I got a mysterious error. Any help is welcome.

```
[ 90%] Building CXX object ThirdParty/ioss/vtkioss/CMakeFiles/ioss.dir/Ioss_ParallelUtils.C.o
/home/common/toolkits/VTK-9.2.0.rc1/ThirdParty/ioss/vtkioss/Ioss_ParallelUtils.C:423:80: error: specialization of \u2018template<class T> void vtkioss_Ioss::ParallelUtils::broadcast(T&, int) const\u2019 in different namespace [-fpermissive]
 template <> void Ioss::ParallelUtils::broadcast(std::string &my_str, int root) const
                                                                                ^~~~~
In file included from /home/common/toolkits/VTK-9.2.0.rc1/ThirdParty/ioss/vtkioss/Ioss_ParallelUtils.C:8:0:
/home/common/toolkits/VTK-9.2.0.rc1/ThirdParty/ioss/vtkioss/Ioss_ParallelUtils.h:134:32: error:   from definition of \u2018template<class T> void vtkioss_Ioss::ParallelUtils::broadcast(T&, int) const\u2019 [-fpermissive]
     template <typename T> void broadcast(T &value, int root = 0) const;
                                ^~~~~~~~~
/home/common/toolkits/VTK-9.2.0.rc1/ThirdParty/ioss/vtkioss/Ioss_ParallelUtils.C:464:91: error: specialization of \u2018template<class T> void vtkioss_Ioss::ParallelUtils::broadcast(std::vector<INT>&, int) const\u2019 in different namespace [-fpermissive]
 void Ioss::ParallelUtils::broadcast(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> &my_value, int root) const
                                                                                           ^~~~~
In file included from /home/common/toolkits/VTK-9.2.0.rc1/ThirdParty/ioss/vtkioss/Ioss_ParallelUtils.C:8:0:
/home/common/toolkits/VTK-9.2.0.rc1/ThirdParty/ioss/vtkioss/Ioss_ParallelUtils.h:135:32: error:   from definition of \u2018template<class T> void vtkioss_Ioss::ParallelUtils::broadcast(std::vector<INT>&, int) const\u2019 [-fpermissive]
     template <typename T> void broadcast(std::vector<T> &value, int root = 0) const;
                                ^~~~~~~~~


ThirdParty/ioss/vtkioss/CMakeFiles/ioss.dir/build.make:733: recipe for target 'ThirdParty/ioss/vtkioss/CMakeFiles/ioss.dir/Ioss_ParallelUtils.C.o' failed
make[2]: *** [ThirdParty/ioss/vtkioss/CMakeFiles/ioss.dir/Ioss_ParallelUtils.C.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:9679: recipe for target 'ThirdParty/ioss/vtkioss/CMakeFiles/ioss.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ThirdParty/ioss/vtkioss/CMakeFiles/ioss.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:135: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: The error must have been printed out before the lines you posted. Please add the lines preceeding the error to the queston.

Comment: I add the lines preceeding the error message.